# How can I generate multiple CSS files in Vue CLI 3?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I am just starting a new app with Vue CLI 3 and as part of the app we need to be able to support dynamic themes (loaded by host name). With this in mind, I'm trying to get the build to generate an additional CSS file for each theme.

Currently I have 2 test themes set up and (weirdly) the theme file classes are being added to the main CSS file which renders them somewhat useless.

Is there something simple that I'm missing from the configuration to get this to work? I've spent hours hunting through the docs on this but I'm getting a bit stuck now.

I have tried using style-resources-loader but that just created a huge CSS duplication problem.

I'm looking for 2 key things here...

1. Tell Vue CLI / WebPack NOT to import the theme SCSS files into the main CSS file.
2. Tell Vue CLI / WebPack to build an extra CSS file from each theme file.

Comment: Is this a create, serve or build problem? - "Static assets placed in the public folder will simply be copied and not go through webpack"

Comment: serve and build - These aren't static assets - These are scss files so they need to be compiled to css files in the theme directory, ideally without hashes added to them.

Comment: @Jleibham Yes - I did. I imported the SCSS file from a Javascript file and then dynamically loaded that JavaScript file through using a Plugin.